# Query Execution takes more time in bitmap index

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

My table has 1 million records. I want to fetch only the inactive user from the table. The query execution takes more than 10 minutes. Even though I am 
using index.
STATUS has only two values Either Y or N. So i have created the bitmap index for that column.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT CUSTOMER NAME,MOBILE NUMBER,ACCOUNT NUMBER,CUSTOMER ID,REGISTARTION DATE from REGISTRATION where STATUS='N';

Plan hash value: 2615581521

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                           |   960K|    66M|  9880   (1)| 00:01:59 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ALL                |                           |   960K|    66M|  9880   (1)| 00:01:59 |     1 |1048575|
|   2 |   PARTITION HASH ALL                |                           |   960K|    66M|  9880   (1)| 00:01:59 |     1 |     4 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| REGISTRATION              |   960K|    66M|  9880   (1)| 00:01:59 |     1 |1048575|
|   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|*  5 |      BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE      | IDX_REGISTRATION_7        |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("STATUS"='N')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=11)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to improve the performance of the above query?

Comment: What do the statistics look like on the index? Do they have histogram?

Comment: Thanks, @MAT I am newbie to oracle.I don't have an idea about histogram. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Looks like a partitioned and sub-partitioned table with the query running single threaded (no parallel hints visible, or showing in the plan)

Comment: Usually a single Bitmap-Index is rather useless. Typical use-case is to have several Bitmap-Indexes - each one with low cardinality but in combination they become highly selective.Consider to make two partitions, one for each STATUS.

Comment: Are you sure the table only has 1 million records?  Or is this query only returning 1 million records out of many more?  I have a feeling this is a ginormous table - you can check the size with `select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'REGISTRATION';`

Comment: @JonHeller, yes the table has only 9,60,000 records. The query return around 4,00,000 records

Comment: @MAT, yes we have histogram.The column has frequency histogram